# Is PostScript access from TeX (via PSTricks or TikZ) safe?

Tags: tikz-pgf, pstricks, postscript

PSTricks and TikZ grant us access to PostScript. Is it safe?

I meant: Is there a vulnerability hole open for someone to exploit?

Edit: I just found that compiling PSTricks with `xelatex` might be unsafe because `dNOSAFER` must be enabled as explained in ["News" section on date 2012-05-26](http://tug.org/PSTricks/main.cgi/). Is it correct?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Usually these days the postscript is converted to pdf or otherwise processed by a ghostscript based interpretor.  `ghostscript` has an option to disable operations that you may not want to allow when running code from an unknown source:

> -dSAFER
>
> Disables  the "deletefile" and "renamefile" operators and the ability to open files in any mode other than read-only.
>   This strongly recommended for spoolers, conversion scripts  or  other  sensitive  environments where  a  badly  written  or  malicious  PostScript program code must be prevented from changing important files.

Comment: So compiling PSTricks with `xelatex` might be unsafe because `dNOSAFER` must be enabled as explained in ["News" section on date 2012-05-26](http://tug.org/PSTricks/main.cgi/)?

Comment: @Karl'sstudents hmm That site just says to add NOSAFER without saying exactly which pstricks features need it (I would have thought most would not) (oh unless it prevents ghostscript writing the pdf file? But that doesn't seem right as conversion scripts are an example where you _want_ -dSAFER) if you have NOSAFER the main danger is not pstricks itself of course but tex files just writing literal postscript code to the dvi file

Comment: @DavidCarlisle: it makes no sense to use the option `-dSAFER` when converting _own_ PostScript files into PDF. And for PSTricks it makes _absolutely_ no sense.

Comment: @Herbert But if I take a random TeX file from the internet (say an MWE from this site) then it may load pstricks or tikz or any other sensible package but that isn't really the concern, it may just directly use postscript `\special` hidden in some macro expansions that can place arbitrary postscript. For the same reason that write18 is disabled or restricted by default, it seems that you should have -dSAFER by default if that is at all possible.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle: with PSTricks it makes no sense because some packages need to run external PostScript files.

Comment: @Herbert sure, but some packages need write18 but that doesn't mean that unrestricted write18 should be enabled by default, it is restricted by default and it's a user option to change the site config or specify it on the command line every time. It's an annoyance but unfortunately that's the world we live in.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle: I was talking about `-dSafer` (GhostScript) and not `write18` (TeX)

Comment: @Herbert yes I know but the issues are the same. If it is necessary to make write18 an explicit user option turned off by default why would the same reasons not apply to -dsafer?

Comment: @DavidCarlisle: `\special{ps: (foo.pro) run }
bar \bye` can be run with `tex -no-shell-escape <file>` but not with `ps2pdf -dSAFER <file>.ps`

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/7960/discussion-between-david-carlisle-and-herbert)

Answer (score 4):

I would say that it is safe at compile time, since PSTricks and TikZ only *write* PostScript in a file, but do not *execute* it.

The security hazards are related to the execution of the PostScript code, which is done in the PostScript interpreter (viewer) or in the printer.

In principle, PS is a turing-complete language, and it even has the possibility of open files for reading/writing, so if the interpreter allows it to do that, then the security risk is real.

This is what [RFC1341](http://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc1341.txt) (about MIME types) says about PostScript (sec 7.4.2):

> The execution  of  general-purpose  PostScript  interpreters entails
>   serious   security  risks,  and  implementors  are discouraged from
>   simply sending PostScript email  bodies  to "off-the-shelf" 
>   interpreters.   While it is usually safe to send PostScript to a
>   printer, where the potential  for  harm is  greatly constrained,
>   implementors should consider all of the  following  before  they  add 
>   interactive  display   of PostScript bodies to their mail readers.
>
> The remainder of this section outlines some, though probably not  all,
>   of  the possible problems with sending PostScript through the mail.
>   [...]

You can read the rest in the RFC, but basically it can rename, delete, create, etc. files. It can even load an execute machine code (kind of TeX's `\write18`). It can alter parameters in the interpreter which can be retained across documents, altering the way other documents are processed (i.e. it is possible to "infect" the interpreter), etc. Not to mention the possibility of bugs in the interpreter which could be exploited.

However, I don't know if all those risk are purely theoretical, or if there was indeed any actual case of PS-exploit.

Comment: PStricks writes code which runs PS-files